# Request sent from Swagger UI not resulting in Postman x-www-form-urlencoded response

Tags: oauth, swagger, openapi, x-www-form-urlencoded

I'm currently configuring a Swagger file to utilize OAuth to retrieve tokens from a site. For brevity, I have removed my schemes and most of my paths as those are fine.

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.2",
  "info": {
    "title": "swagger",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": ""
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "url"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/oauth_token.do": {
      "post": {
        "requestBody": {
          "required": true,
          "content": {
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded": {
              "schema": {
                "type": "object"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
     "securitySchemes": {
      "OAuth": {
        "type": "oauth2",
        "flows": {
          "password": {
            "tokenUrl": "/oauth_token.do",
            "refreshUrl": "/oauth_token.do",
            "scopes": {
              "useraccount": "utilize user account"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }
  "security": [
    {
      "OAuth": ["useraccount"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The endpoint for this API specifies that I should use `x-www-form-urlencoded` in the header as the Content-Type. When executing this request in Postman, it returns 200 with the desired response.

However, with `https://editor.swagger.io` I input the same postman request to get the `fetch failed` error with my `Authorize` button. To test for this, I created a custom `path` that specifies that the content should be `x-www-form-urlencoded` and this also fails.

So, what am I missing in this case? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue was I did not fill out some portions I added on the response for path. Instead I opted to only leave `description` for the 200 response.

The main error I'm getting now is CORS related which is unrelated to the original question. I'll mark this answered for now.